# Azure automation Schedule timezone

Tags: azure

Can anyone guide me on which time zone is used when we create schedules for Azure Automation runbooks. Is it UTC and do we need to keep that in mind when creating the schedules for the runbooks

Thanks

Comment: Based on `MSDN forum thread`: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/bd48db3f-a7ce-4ad8-98f8-2384ae5fdf47/in-what-timezone-will-my-schedule-run?forum=azureautomation, it is actually based on your local time zone. However this thread is 2 years old so I am not sure if anything's changed in past 2 years regarding this.

Answer (score 1):

Azure Automation schedules now have time zone support so that you can choose the time zone you want the schedule to run on. However, the schedule defaults to your local time zone.